# SSL Certificate language

Tags: ssl

in SSL Certificate what is this language called?

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID+TCCAuGgAwIBAgIJAJE8Kx55CCV6MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGSMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJTQTEPMA0GA1UECAwGUml5YWRoMRQwEgYDVQQHDAtSaXlhZGggQ2l0eTEQ
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: It's a base64 encoded form.

Comment: @vidarlo Would you be willing to post an answer about that?

Comment: @EliahKagan In my opinion this question is offtopic as it is not about ubuntu. I'd suggest security SE as a resort for it :)

Comment: @vidarlo This would be OT over on Security.SE (I'm a user there as well)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a language. It is simply the certificate, and the BEGIN/END are simply markers to state the content in between is the certificate data.

Answer (score 0):

An SSL cert does not have a 'language', as SSL is a protocol or set of standards defining a way for two systems to communicate.